# A question about a limit that should be solved by considering Riemann sums.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I was hoping you guys could help me with a tough problem from my final exam. It stumped me.

We are asked to evaluate:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}(e^{1/n}+e^{2/n}+e^{3/n}+\cdots+e^{n/n}) $$
As a hint they tell us we can think of this as a Riemann sum from $[0, 1]$

So then I think to myself that this looks awfully similar to the limits definition of an integral, so I tried rewriting it this way:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{1/x} dx $$

But then I couldn't solve the problem for the life of me. Where did I go wrong?!

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone who helped me solve the problem. For those who are wondering, I didn't write the correct integral above. To solve the problem successfully I should have done:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^x dx $$

It sure is painful to miss the last problem on a final by such a slim margin!

Comment: Should be $e^x$. The partition of $[0,1]$ is $x_k = k/n$ with $k=1,...n$. You have$ f(x_k) = e^{x_k} = e^{k/n} $

Comment: @SpineFeast I'm not really following what you did there... Could you post a link to explain the whole $ x_k $ thing?

Comment: Just let $f(x) = e^x$ and write the standard Riemann sum for n subintervals.

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "Riemann" in the question.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title into something that will be more pertinent for future references or searches ("a tough problem" isn't the best title, otherwise most titles would contain it, and it is not very discriminant as a kind of keyword). If you don't agree, you can revert to the ancient title...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, my title was probably a little too vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commenters noted, you have the function wrong - it is $e^{x}$ since the partition of $[0,1]$ is $1/n,2/n,\dots,n/n.$

You can also solve it directly. Setting $u=e^{1/n}$ the above can be written:

$$\frac{1}{n}(u+u^2+\cdots +u^n) = \frac{u}{n}\frac{u^n-1}{u-1} = \frac{u(e-1)}{n(u-1)}$$

But $n(u-1)=\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n}$, so as $n\to\infty$, $n(u-1)$ converges to the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$, which is $1$. Since $u\to 1$, you get a limit of $e-1$.

Comment: That is some mathematical witchcraft you worked there. I like the way you think!

Comment: This is the way you do it if you _don't_ use the hint.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^x\,dx.$

The variable $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.  If it does that by steps of size $1/n$, then it takes the values $1/n, 2/n, 3/n,\ldots, n/n.$

Comment: I think I understand now. So $ \frac 1 n $ is equivalent to $ \frac 1 \infty $ which pretty much is equal to 0 (the lower limit of integration)? If so, damn, I was so close to getting this right on my final.

Comment: What we're saying is $$ \frac 1 n \left( f\left(\frac 1 n\right) + f\left(\frac 2 n\right) + f\left(\frac 3 n\right) + \cdots + f\left(\frac n n\right) \right) \to \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx, $$ where $f(x) = e^x$, so that $\displaystyle f\left(\frac k n\right) = e^{k/n}.\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. The LaTeX makes it much easier to understand!